# One email login for all the Stack Exchange linked sites without registration in every site

Tags: support, stack-overflow

Is it possible to create a login for a Stack Exchange site, and then using the same information to log in to others sites without creating an account every time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're held in different databases so you will have to create an account each time, though this could be concealed from the user.

However, as they're held in different databases this would, theoretically, violate the [privacy policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy) and/or [Safe Harbor's rules](http://export.gov/safeharbor/), which, thankfully, Stack Exchange has signed up to.

Stack Exchange should not be using your data without your permission. The creation of an account, linked to your other accounts (the crucial point), without your explicit permission does not conform to this requirement.

[Just ask Google](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2013/apr/02/google-privacy-policy-legal-threat-europe).

I don't see a problem. All you have to do is click yes for each site you sign up to. It's one more click and so makes almost no difference to you. More importantly, it enables you to create accounts on different sites, without being forced to associate them. So, you can have an acknowledged account for a site like [bicycles](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/); but, if you don't want your employer to know your political affiliations, you can have a different one for [politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/).

It would be possible for there to be a tick-box on http://stackexchange.com, say, which stops this from happening and provides you with all the appropriate warnings. However, I doubt this is worth the development time.

Comment: Thanks For the explanation!Accept as answer and vote you up for good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can simply use the "Log in with Stack Exchange" option when you want to sign in. Now you just need to log into every Stack Exchange site with the Stack Exchange option

[image: Log in]

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP meant on the page after that you have to click the "confirm and create this account" and that's the `without creating an account every time` part of the question

Comment: @Mike Ahh, I didn't realize that

Comment: Thanks For Help vote you up!

Answer (score -1):

yaaa just you type url(http://careers.stackoverflow.com/users/login) in address bar
then you get screen in that on left side of screen have Create a new account » --> click that 
REGISTRE YOU'R account and conform mail cheack from given email id to conform your account after conform your account
               you post queries and get response of your question from stack overflow..

Comment: Appreciate for your answer but please first read question always then only answer.